# Malicious Resources on Linux Server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, upload, malicious

When creating a website, I often include custom fonts (which I upload via FTP and reference via CSS).  I get these font files from various locations on the web.

I was wondering: is it possible for a website to offer malicious font files for download that could compromise my server once they're uploaded and rendered to the user?

On Linux systems, is this possible for any file that isn't explicitly executable?  By "explicitly executable," I mean something like a bash script or PHP file.

If there is a risk involved, how can it be mitigated?

Thanks.

Comment: The server doesn't render the fonts, the user's computer does.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance; I'm new to Linux.

Does the server ever "see" the contents of the file as it's presented to the user?

Comment: The server sees the content but doesn't interact with he files/data it isn't explicitely configured to interpret. An analogy would be how a bartender doesn't get drunk of the drinks he pours.

Comment: Nor did the waiter eat the food he served me at the restaurant... Transmitting a file and executing or interpreting it are radically different things, and this has nothing to do with Linux.

Comment: I see.  One of you please post this as an answer so I can accept it.  If you could, please also point me to a resource that lists what file types are executable on a typical server.

Comment: "please also point me to a resource that lists what file types are executable on a typical server. " Executables. Executables are the file types that are executable on a server.

Comment: @mfinni A PHP script isn't technically an executable but will execute on a server and can do damage.

Comment: Yup, and there's word macros, and bash and perl scripts. I know that. But given the question, as it was asked, I felt like giving a snarky reply.